# Getting PyScripter Portable to work with IPython

Tags: python, ide, pyscripter, portable-python

How can I set PyScripter up to work with IPython as the "embedded" interpreter rather than the plain Python one?
I am using portable python.

I've tried for a few hours with no success.
I imagined it's just a C/L parameter.
But that doesn't seem the case.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work but you could try the following in the embedded interpreter:

```
>>> from IPython import embed
>>> embed()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible as PyScripter does this based on a specified Python engine. For portable installation [these settings](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_use_PyScripter_with_Portable_%28Movable%29_Python?) are used and this is also what Portable Python shortcut

> PyScripter-Portable.exe

does to set up the environment and configure Python engine to be used.